# QGIS2.4.0: Cannot import qgis module in python "from qgis._core import * \n DLL Load Error"

Tags: qgis, python

Having some trouble importing qgis into python. I'm very new to python so it could be a simple mistake. The path seems to be correct. It gets this far:

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
    File "qgis\core\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from qgis._core import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```